# Plasma virtual desktop change with scroll wheel bounces back

Tags: kde, plasma

I would like to use Plasma's feature of changing virtual desktops using the mouse wheel over the background, but when I try to do that it bounces back.

It only works if I make a tiny movement with the scroll wheel, but it's too easy to go too far, so its too counter intuitive and the method becomes useless for me.

How could I make this work right?